# Can't login to gmail via Selenium Webdriver, asks for recovery email?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver version 3.4 and chromedriver 2.35.528157. My test consists of entering a system through google, so when I click login through google it asks me to enter my email. When I enter my email and click next it asks for the screenshot attached, it does not get to enter password screen.[image] I tried adding a recovery mail but if I follow the steps it just sends a verification code to the recovery email and complicates things all over. The weird part is if I do this manually in an incognito browser, Firefox driver or in headless mode on chrome everything works fine.

Comment: Why don't you check the email using IMAP or POP3 instead of doing this this way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22316379/1872682

Comment: Because my application has an option login with google, and in order to login with google I need to enter mail and password, when I enter the mail and click next the screenshot happens, when I access the email I don't interact with it, i go to another address straight away, i just need the cookies that I am logged in via google account.

Comment: You can retrieve your cookie details and then load them in the Selenium session to bypass those steps?

Comment: I thought of that option but the application doesn't send the user and pass with every request, it creates a temporary token from google and saves it for a certain period of time.

Comment: @Gudzo, did you solve your problem? Thanks.

Comment: @RatmirAsanov No luck so far

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
variableForTextFieldId.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I was having the same issue as you when using either .click() or .submit(). However, I ended up using the Keys variable ENTER and it allowed me to get to the next part of login (The password screen).

Answer (score 0):

You must be using the class for the **xpath**, which is same for **'Next'** and **'Forgot email'** links. Therefore it clicks **Forgot Email** and lands on the Email Recovery page.
There are 3 classes in the Next button itself. Try using the id of the first one.
Command:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();
```

This will lead you to the Password page. Let me know it helped.