# Ideas on how to save Gmail email replies to a database?

Tags: java, gmail, gmail-api, google-workspace, email-client

We have a custom CRM where we can send emails to clients. Emails are sent from the users Gmail account and when sent from the CRM we have a record of all outbound communications. However, replies are only visible in the user's Gmail inbox. I want a solution for storing email replies for emails sent from the system to the communications log.

Our dev partner says it will 6+ months to basically recreate a Gmail client, which doesn't seem right. This seems like a pretty standard feature in just about every CRM or ticket management system. Do you have any ideas on how we can implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You could process incoming emails programmatically via IMAP. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263530/accessing-emails-from-gmail-using-imap-javamail-api) for example.